# How do you do a page redirect after a timeout in firefox when the computer is in fast user switching (Windows 7 [winkey+L])

Tags: javascript, firefox, redirect, timeout

In Firefox with JavaScript I set up a timeout that after the timeout occurs it changes the page essentially equivalent to this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.href = "http://google.com";
}, 3000);
```

The problem is in Firefox the browser doesn't render the new contents when the computer is in fast user switching and occasionally it renders parts of the new page on top of the old one (keeping the old contents but overlaying them with parts of the new contents). To test this copy that code into the Firefox console hit winkey+L wait 3 seconds and then log back in.

I tried solutions like:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    requestAnimationFrame(function(){
         window.location.href = "http://google.com";
    });
}, 3000);
```

Assuming that once the browser can animate it should be free to draw, but this still doesn't fix the issue (though with that change it waits for some interaction with the window after the lock to change the url in the window). I've also tried using window.location.assign and window.location.replace to no avail.

So far the only semi functional fix has been to set up event listeners for any event firing on the window and once an event fires then do the window.location.href stuff.

This appears to be a bug in Firefox, however I'm fairly certain it has been around for a while, roughly 3 years (based on bug reports in similar products within the company). **What I am wondering is if there is a better method to doing this?**

Interestingly if you change the window.location.href to alert() or document.write() or any function that causes a render, it fails to render properly while the computer is locked.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "locked" here? Also what OS are you talking about?

Comment: @Pointy fast user switching mode and I know it occurs in windows 7 but its possible it occurs in other versions of windows.

Answer (score 0):

if your lock is from javascript you will need to yield to the main thread to allow the event queue to fire the function queued by the timeout.

for example

```
var items = makeLotsOfData

// bad
for(var i = 0, l = items.length; i<l; i++){
   doSuperExpensiveThing(items[i]);
}

// good
function doThings(start, end, items){
   for(var i = start;i<end; i++){
      doSuperExpensiveThing(items[i]);
   }
}

var idx = 0;
var chunk = 100;
var len = items.length;
function do(){
   if(idx < len){
       var end;
       if(idx+chunk > len){
           end = len;
       }else{
           end = idx+chunk
       }
       doThings(idx, end);
       idx = end;
       setTimeout(do,1);// this yeilds the next call so the event stack can run
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry the lock is done in the OS, in windows you would hit winkey+L to lock the computer. I mean fast user switching mode.

Comment: got it so the os is locking the screen and probably backgrounding firefox, yeah different issue

Comment: Ya, after your answer and pointy's comment i had to rewrite the question a bit to be clearer, I wasn't thinking it could be interpreted as thread locked stupidly.